# asp.net core project.json intellisense doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using visual studio community 2015 update 3 with web essential installed. my problem is when ever I create a new asp.net core project the intellisense in project.json works only for few day and then it stops working. no intellisense what so ever.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the project.json file, there is a pull-down menu on top of the editor. Click on it and select `http://json.schemastore.org/project`, then save.

The pull-down allows you to choose a json schema, which will be used for auto-completion.

Also see this [MSDN Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/10/intellisense-for-json-schema-in-the-json-editor/) for a more visual guide.